# CommandField delete button showing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a CommandField Delete imagebutton but it does not work. here is a snippet which i have tried:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
        int indx = row.RowIndex;

        using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {                
                var delete = (from a in context.Property_basics where a.prop_id == GridView1.Rows[indx].Cells[0].Text select a).Single();

                    delete.delete_status = 1;
                    context.SubmitChanges();
                    GridView1.DeleteRow(indx);                
            }
        }
}
```

.aspx:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image"  HeaderText="Delete" DeleteImageUrl="~/wp-content/themes/realia/assets/img/500px-Delete_Icon2.png" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

the exception which it shows is:

> *Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer.Parent.Parent;
```

Or Like

Setting Command Arguments

```
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" 


int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


GridViewRow row = ProductsGridView.Rows[index];
```

Comment: did the changes but now the exception it throws is: "Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.admin_panel_master' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'."

Comment: now its throwing: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'."

Comment: @HaiderKhattak You can try Second Solution

Comment: instead of rowcommand why don't try your code in gridview_rowdeleting ? You need to pass only datakey in your gridview aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching the row you should use the `CommandArgument` to get the `RowIndex`. In the case of a [`CommandField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandfield(v=vs.110).aspx) the `CommandArgument` is the `RowIndex`. In the case of the `CommandArgument` passed on a standard control it's the actual command argument.

```
int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ASPX will look like this :

```
       <asp:Gridview id = Gridview1 runat = "server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
```

Code Behind : You can do it like this,

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(dg1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)dg1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
   // write your code. to delete 

}
```